# Can somebody explain this lambda?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

I'm implementing a date picker fragment and I have the following code:

DatePickerFragment:

```
class DatePickerFragment(val listener: (day: Int, month: Int, year: Int) -> Unit) : DialogFragment(),
    DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    override fun onDateSet(view: DatePicker?, year: Int, month: Int, dayOfMonth: Int) {
        listener(dayOfMonth, month, year)
    }

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        val c = Calendar.getInstance()
        val year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR)
        val month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH)
        val day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
        val picker = DatePickerDialog(activity as Context, this, year, month, day)
        return picker
    }
}
```

and the implementation in my activity

```
private fun showDatePickerDialog() {

    val datePicker = DatePickerFragment { day, month, year -> onDateSelected(day, month, year) }
    datePicker.show(childFragmentManager, "datePicker")
  }

  private fun onDateSelected(day: Int, month: Int, year: Int) {
    val combinedCal = GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-06:00"))
    combinedCal.set(year, month, day)
    val selectedDate = DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(combinedCal.timeInMillis)
    expenseAddViewModel.editTextDate.value = selectedDate
    expenseAddViewModel.setTimeStamp(combinedCal.timeInMillis)
  }
```

What I can't understand is this line:

```
val datePicker = DatePickerFragment { day, month, year -> onDateSelected(day, month, year) }
```

I don't understand how the **onDateSelected** function is called and how it get the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here listener is a function that has day, month, and year as arguments and return nothing i.e. unit.
val listener: (day: Int, month: Int, year: Int) -> Unit

Here you are calling listener function passing dayOfMonth, month, year as arguments.

```
override fun onDateSet(view: DatePicker?, year: Int, month: Int, dayOfMonth: Int) {
    listener(dayOfMonth, month, year)
}
```

Now in DatePickerFragment you are passing listener as a Lambda.

```
DatePickerFragment { day, month, year -> onDateSelected(day, month, year) }
```

Here `day, month, year -> onDateSelected(day, month, year)` is the implementation of the listener function, you can think of it as:

```
    fun listener(day:Int, month:Int, year:Int){
      onDateSelected(day, month, year)
    }
```